# Getting Product Name of Mobile Device (I.E. IPad 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have been trying to get the Product Name with its version (Iphone 6, Ipad 3 etc) but I am only finding the product name and the version of the browser within navigator(ie navigator.userAgent). The same thing goes with libraries which seem to just look like they are parsing out navigator(i.e https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js) .

Does anyone know how I can get the information I am looking for or is this just possible?

Comment: which programming language ?

Comment: jQuery  or javascript